# Countability of Fibonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, fibonacci-numbers, formal-proofs

Fibonacci series is an infinite sequence of integers, starting with $1$ and $2$ and defined recursively after that, for the $n$th term in the array, as $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$. How is the countability of Fibonacci sequence proven?

Comment: The Fibonacci series has an index of a natural number. That’s the definition of countability.

Comment: There is a bijection between the natural numbers and F(n)

Comment: To check that its values are an infinite set, just notice that it is strictly increasing ($F(n-2)> 0$).

Comment: Ask yourself: how could it NOT be countable, given a standard definition of "countable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A set $S$ is countable iff there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $S$*

This means that we have to find that bijection, and as the Fibonacci Numbers is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, it must be countable. 
   Or stated differently, we could just map a number $n$ to the $n$th fibonacci number.